# How to sample songs in my headphones without it playing through speakers/monitors?

Tags: headphones

Basically I'm trying to get an output to my headphones WHILE A SONG IS PLAYING THROUGH THE MONITORS but without it going to both outputs. I'm supposed to be doing a DJ gig and this problem came up which doesn't let me mix on the fly. I mean I could probably just create a mix at home but what if the party goes on for longer than I predicted? Any help on this would be super, thanks in advance to anyone who knows how to do this.

Comment: 2 distinct outputs, listen & broadcast; & software that can recognise those concepts.

Comment: What is your setup? Do you have a mixer? An audio interface with more than 1 stereo output? It's probably a good idea to do more research and practice, so you know how everything works, and more importantly, you know what you're doing, before doing a gig.

Comment: Its just a laptop and a huge speaker for now. Think you could point me in the right direction in terms of hardware?

Answer (score 1):

What you need (in terms of hardware) is an interface that has multiple outputs, and DJ software that allows you to bus to these multiple outputs. A laptop generally has a single stereo audio output and thus you can only bus a single mix to it. An interface with multiple outputs will allow you to bus the master mix to the speakers and a cue mix to your headphones. Keep in mind that what ever interface you chose needs either 2 stereo outputs or 4 mono outputs to make a setup like this work as properly. Most interfaces have at least a stereo output and a headphone output however you cannot always independently bus to the headphone output some older interfaces have the headphone output always mirror the main output. Just make sure that you can independently bus to the main out and the headphone out before purchasing a unit.